# Kingfisher Library removes images from cache

Tags: swift, caching, kingfisher

Currently, I am loading images from the swift Kingfisher library as such :

```
   if imageURL != nil {
        let imageConvertedUrl = URL(string: imageURL!)

        photo.kf.setImage(with: imageConvertedUrl, options: [.diskCacheExpiration(.days(3)), .memoryCacheExpiration(.days(3))]) { result in
            // `result` is either a `.success(RetrieveImageResult)` or a `.failure(KingfisherError)`
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                self.spinnerView.isHidden = true
                print(value.cacheType)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error) // The error happens
                self.spinnerView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```

I can turn off the internet, relaunch the app, and load the image from the cache without trouble. However, after a few minutes, if I reopen the image without internet it will not load and I am faced with the error message:

```
Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=
```

I am not sure why the image doesn't load from the cache, as I have set the `.diskCacheExpiration` to 3 days so I would assume it would load from the cache for up to three days.

Comment: Could It possible have anything to do with images storing on the disk? Would adding `ImageCache.default.memoryStorage.config.totalCostLimit = 1` fix the problem?

Comment: I tried sitting the images not on the RAM and the problem persists. After turning off the internet, the images will only continue to load for a while until eventually I reopen the app and they will not load from the cache.